# How to return more than 1 value of string?

Tags: java, string, encryption

I'm a newbie here in need of some help. I have a code here that is use to decrypt data. It is working meaning it can decrypt the data, but the problem is; it can only show 1 value of the decrypted data(line 29) instead of 3 or more depend on how I want it (how do i get it to also decrypt the data on line 30 and line 31?). Below i posted the related code to my problem, hope anyone here can help me with this problem.

```
public class CipherUtils
{
static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CipherUtils.class);
    private static byte[] key = "xxxxxx".getBytes();
    private static byte[] iv = "xxxxxx".getBytes();

public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt)
{
    try
    {
        //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("aes/cbc/nopadding");
        final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        //cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey,ips);
        final String decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt)));
        return decryptedString.trim();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.error("Error while decrypting : " + strToDecrypt , e);
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    String a = CipherUtils.decrypt("yXTVA6oG4kWOlvfKN/qXwa3VgEyiBu4kkgKh9WHt0s8="
                                  ,"yX7JI7IaExK3eBC6BU5RdCvkCrAAcyV3YTmHqYH5nG0="                                               
                                  ,"yj56tfZEh3405yEwladp+ml/nk/h8Cx56XnP5Ycdeio=");
    System.out.println(">>>"+a.trim());
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok..... so you want to decrypt multiple strings and then what you want as return ?? you want to concat the result of three decrpted strings or first you want to concat three strings and then decrypt ??

Comment: I dont want to concat the result, i just want to decrypt it individually, and shows all the result.

Answer (score 1):

Your method decrypt only takes a single parameter (named strToDecrypt), yet you are passing three.

You could do several things here, the easiest would be to simly call decrypt 3 times, each with a different string.
You could also rewrite list to iterate over a list instead.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm

Comment: then how can i make it to takes 3 parameter so that i can decrypt 3 data?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CipherUtils
{
  static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CipherUtils.class);
  private static byte[] key = "xxxxxx".getBytes();
  private static byte[] iv = "xxxxxx".getBytes();

  public static String[] decrypt(String[] strToDecrypt){
     try{
       String[] strDecrypted;
       //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
       Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("aes/cbc/nopadding");
       final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
       IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
       //cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
       cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey,ips);
       for(int i =0;i<strToDecrypt.length ; i++){
          final String decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt [i])));
          strDecrypted[i] = decryptedString ;
       }
       return strDecrypted;    
     }catch (Exception e){
         log.error("Error while decrypting : " + strToDecrypt , e);
      }
     return null;
 }

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
     String array[] =      {"yXTVA6oG4kWOlvfKN/qXwa3VgEyiBu4kkgKh9WHt0s8=","yX7JI7IaExK3eBC6BU5RdCvkCrAAcyV3YTmHqYH5nG0=","yj56tfZEh3405yEwladp+ml/nk/h8Cx56XnP5Ycdeio="};

     String a = CipherUtils.decrypt(array);
     System.out.println(">>>"+a.trim());
  }
}
```

What I have done is I have taken all your strings to decrypt inside a String array and passed it to the method. Then inside the method, i decrypt the string and add it to another array. And then when done, I return the array containing all the decrypted lines. You can then fetch it from the array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'm going to try it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String[] decrypt(String[] strToDecrypt)
{
    String decryptedString[] = new String[strToDecrypt.length];
    for(int i = 0;i<strToDecrypt.length;i++) {
    try
    {
        //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("aes/cbc/nopadding");
        final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        //cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey,ips);
        decryptedString[i] = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt[i])));

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.error("Error while decrypting : " + strToDecrypt[i] , e);
    }
    }return decryptedString;
}
```